# UIWebView or Core Text

Tags: ios, ios5

New to Objective C and IOS.

I am writing an app that pulls in data via JSON from a PHP server.  At a high level, that data is often in arrays that contain different types of data (headlines, body text, certain data types that require certain formatting like italics, etc.).  To render a page, I plan to just walk the arrays and alter the size, formatting of text as a new data element appears (i.e., this is a headline, make it bold and bigger... this is a sub-headline, make it italics, etc.)

I will need to display the text (and pull some images in as well) on a single view.  The application won't know the structure of the data until it receives the JSON (for example, when, where, or how often headlines show up). I may, or may not want to be able to capture actions from the rendered text (i.e., clicking on a headline spawning a new view, etc.)

What do people typically do?  I know Core Text is out there, and, from what I've seen, it's fairly difficult to work with--and, even the tutorials produce pretty bland formatting.  I've also seen indication that people just use a UIWebView and generate the HTML on the fly and just display it using HTML.

If UIWebView is the best and easiest solution, I'll probably just do that.  But, I also don't want to use a technique that is frwoned upon or I will discover down the road has serious limitations.  It also seems a bit strange for an app to (in parts) just be a glorified webpage.  But, perhaps that's what people do given the tools that are available (and, certainly, HTML does what it does fairly well).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I certainly recommend to use a `UIWebView`, unless you're already familiar with CoreText.

I'm currently using a web view myself to show a formatted log in my application. I've several methods which all create specific HTML code and then append the HTML to an `NSMutableString`. Using a `UIWebView` allows you to easily change content.

As CSS is fully available, generating styled pages isn't difficult at all.

JavaScript can be used too, so scrolling your view is just as easy as telling the web view to execute some JavaScript. And of couse the scripting language brings you a lot of other features, too.

Comment: Thanks.  Are you aware of any good HTML libraries that are compatible with iOS 5 ARC so I don't have to hand code HTML?